# Understading and creating XML inner chained sequences

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xsd

I am tasked to recreate an inner chained sequence using the XSLT starter code that has been provided to me. What I am confused is that I am not sure how to set up the XPaths in the XSLT file.

Currently, I have a few XPaths which are able to go through the items that are provided but they aren't being sequenced properly. Not sure if I am understanding setting the XPaths correctly at all.

I was also given two hints,

At marker 4: There are a lot of ways to create this xpath, the one that gets the points includes begins with not(//item[@

At market 8:There are a lot of ways to create this xpath, the one that gets the points includes these two parts 1) not(//item and 2) //items/@lastItemMarker

Any help and explanation would be greatly appreciated!

My Code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <!--marker #1-->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Sequence Level 2 Exercise</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <a name="top"/>
                <table border="1" cellpadding="10">
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <h1>Sequences</h1>
                            <!--marker #2-->
                            <xsl:for-each select="//items">
                                <!--marker #3-->
                                <xsl:variable name="currItemId" select="."/>
                                <!--marker #4-->
                                <xsl:if test="//item[@id]">
                                    <hr/>
                                    <ol>
                                        <xsl:call-template name="outputSeqLink">
                                            <!--marker #5-->
                                            <xsl:with-param name="currItemId" select="."/>
                                        </xsl:call-template>
                                    </ol>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </td>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <h1>Items</h1>
                            <xsl:for-each select="//item">
                                <hr/>
                                <a name="{@id}"/>
                                <h2>
                                    <a href="#top">
                                        <font size="-2">top</font>
                                    </a>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
                                </h2>
                                <h3>Faked in content</h3>
                                <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk
                                    jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk
                                    aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                                <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk
                                    jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk
                                    aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                                <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk
                                    jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk
                                    aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                                <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk
                                    jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk
                                    aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                                <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk
                                    jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk
                                    aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                                <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk
                                    jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk
                                    aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="outputSeqLink">
        <xsl:param name="currItemId"/>
        <li>
            <!--marker #6-->
            <a href="">
                <!--marker #7-->
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </a>
        </li>
        <!--marker #8-->
        <xsl:if test="//items/@lastItemMarker">
            <!--marker #9-->
            <xsl:variable name="nextItemRefId" select="."/>
            <xsl:call-template name="outputSeqLink">
                <!--marker #10-->
                <xsl:with-param name="currItemId" select="."/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Sample XML file generated by XMLSpy v2008 (http://www.altova.com)-->
<system xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="seqLevel2Exercise.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <items  lastItemMarker="last">
        <item id="i1" title="Siamese Cats" nextItemRefId="i5"/>
        <item id="i2" title="Siamese Dogs" nextItemRefId="i10"/>
        <item id="i3" title="Siamese Twins" nextItemRefId="i9"/>
        <item id="i4" title="Chicago Twins" nextItemRefId="i7"/>
        <item id="i5" title="Fraternal Twins" nextItemRefId="i2"/>
        <item id="i6" title="Fraternal Societies" nextItemRefId="last"/>
        <item id="i7" title="Society of Mind" nextItemRefId="i6"/>
        <item id="i8" title="Mind over Matter" nextItemRefId="i1"/>
        <item id="i9" title="Matters of Fact" nextItemRefId="i4"/>
        <item id="i10" title="Facts and Figures" nextItemRefId="last"/>
    </items>
    </system>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- edited with XMLSpy v2008 (http://www.altova.com) by XMLSpy 2008  Release 2, Partner License for 30 users (valid from 2008-09-05 to 2009-09-30) (University of Washington) -->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="system">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Comment describing your root element</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="items">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="item" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID" use="required"/>
                                    <xs:attribute ref="title" use="required"/>
                                    <xs:attribute name="nextItemRefId" type="xs:IDREF" use="required"/>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="lastItemMarker" type="xs:ID" use="required"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:attribute name="title"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Expected Output:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sequence Level 2 Exercise</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a name="top"/>
        <table border="1" cellpadding="10">
            <tr>
                <td valign="top">
                    <h1>Sequences</h1>
                    <hr/>
                    <ol>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#i3">Siamese Twins</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#i9">Matters of Fact</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#i4">Chicago Twins</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#i7">Society of Mind</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#i6">Fraternal Societies</a>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                    <hr/>
                    <ol>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#i8">Mind over Matter</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#i1">Siamese Cats</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#i5">Fraternal Twins</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#i2">Siamese Dogs</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#i10">Facts and Figures</a>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </td>
                <td valign="top">
                    <h1>Items</h1>
                    <hr/>
                    <a name="i1"/>
                    <h2><a href="#top">
                            <font size="-2">top</font>
                        </a>Siamese Cats</h2>
                    <h3>Faked in content</h3>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <hr/>
                    <a name="i2"/>
                    <h2><a href="#top">
                            <font size="-2">top</font>
                        </a>Siamese Dogs</h2>
                    <h3>Faked in content</h3>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <hr/>
                    <a name="i3"/>
                    <h2><a href="#top">
                            <font size="-2">top</font>
                        </a>Siamese Twins</h2>
                    <h3>Faked in content</h3>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <hr/>
                    <a name="i4"/>
                    <h2><a href="#top">
                            <font size="-2">top</font>
                        </a>Chicago Twins</h2>
                    <h3>Faked in content</h3>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <hr/>
                    <a name="i5"/>
                    <h2><a href="#top">
                            <font size="-2">top</font>
                        </a>Fraternal Twins</h2>
                    <h3>Faked in content</h3>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <hr/>
                    <a name="i6"/>
                    <h2><a href="#top">
                            <font size="-2">top</font>
                        </a>Fraternal Societies</h2>
                    <h3>Faked in content</h3>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <hr/>
                    <a name="i7"/>
                    <h2><a href="#top">
                            <font size="-2">top</font>
                        </a>Society of Mind</h2>
                    <h3>Faked in content</h3>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <hr/>
                    <a name="i8"/>
                    <h2><a href="#top">
                            <font size="-2">top</font>
                        </a>Mind over Matter</h2>
                    <h3>Faked in content</h3>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <hr/>
                    <a name="i9"/>
                    <h2><a href="#top">
                            <font size="-2">top</font>
                        </a>Matters of Fact</h2>
                    <h3>Faked in content</h3>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <hr/>
                    <a name="i10"/>
                    <h2><a href="#top">
                            <font size="-2">top</font>
                        </a>Facts and Figures</h2>
                    <h3>Faked in content</h3>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                    <p>alkdjfasajflkdsajfsdlkf lkjh alksdjflkajflk lkjdsaflk jsflkjsadlkf jdsajlkdsafj lksajflkdsajflkdsajflkjlksadlkj lk aslkfj lkajsdflkflj</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please ask one question at a time, and reduce the code to the minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem - see: [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> recreate an inner chained sequence

I believe the elegant (and also efficient) way to do this would be to start with the items that are marked as being last in their sequence, and work recursively backwards, using a [**key**](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#key) to select the previous item in the sequence.

Here is a minimal example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:key name="prev-item" match="item" use="@nextItemRefId" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('prev-item', 'last')">
                <ol>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                </ol>
            </xsl:for-each>     
        </body>
    </html> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('prev-item', @id)"/>
    <li>
        <a href="#{@id}">
            <xsl:value-of select="@title" />
        </a>
    </li>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, this will return:

**Result**

```
<html>
   <body>
      <ol>
         <li><a href="#i3">Siamese Twins</a></li>
         <li><a href="#i9">Matters of Fact</a></li>
         <li><a href="#i4">Chicago Twins</a></li>
         <li><a href="#i7">Society of Mind</a></li>
         <li><a href="#i6">Fraternal Societies</a></li>
      </ol>
      <ol>
         <li><a href="#i8">Mind over Matter</a></li>
         <li><a href="#i1">Siamese Cats</a></li>
         <li><a href="#i5">Fraternal Twins</a></li>
         <li><a href="#i2">Siamese Dogs</a></li>
         <li><a href="#i10">Facts and Figures</a></li>
      </ol>
   </body>
</html>
```